# React Native - Function doesn't seem to be called

Tags: react-native

I have a simple app with 2 images. When I click on image1, I want to display hello on the console.
But my function doesn't write anything in the console.
I didn't use a function and called directly `console.log` in the 2nd image and it works.

Do you know what is wrong with my function?
(I also used `makeALogHello.bind(this)` but it doesn't change the behavior).

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
      super();
  }

  makeALogHello(){
    console.log("hello");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
          <TouchableOpacity style ={{flex:1}}
                            onPress={() => {this.makeALogHello} }>
              <Image  style ={styles.container}
                      resizeMode="contain"
                      source={require("./images/image1.png")}/>
              <Text>ImageNb1</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity style ={{flex:1}}
                            onPress={() => {console.log("hi")} }>
              <Image  style ={styles.container}
                      resizeMode="contain"
                      source={require("./images/image2.png")}/>
              <Text>ImageNb2</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: try calling it as `this.makeALogHello()`

Comment: very simple... thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function in your arrow function:

```
onPress={() => {this.makeALogHello()} }
```

Or simply pass the reference to your function, without wrapping it:

```
onPress={this.makeALogHello}
```

Comment: `onPress={this.makeALogHello}` is also a (nicer) valid way to do this